# How can I improve unit testing this function

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I want to know if there are other unit tests (I mean other unit tests that I can do without relying on a test database) that I can do for the function getAll in the following class:

```
<?php
namespace Example\Model;

use Example\Lib\PdoConnection;

class UserModel {

    private $pdoConn;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->pdoConn = PdoConnection::getInstance();
    }

    function getAll()
    {
        $arrUsers = array();
        $strSql = "SELECT id, first_name, last_name FROM user";
        $arrData = array();
        try
        {
            $objRes = $this->pdoConn->prepare($strSql);
            $objRes->execute($arrData);
            $objRes->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $arrUsers = $objRes->fetchAll();
        }
        catch(\PDOException $e) {
            error_log($e->getMessage());
        }
        return $arrUsers;
    }
```

Here is how I am testing it:

```
function testGetAll()
{   
    $stubUserModel = $this->getMockBuilder('Example\Model\UserModel')
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->getMock();

    $stubUserModel->method('getAll')
    ->willReturn(array(array('id' => 1, 'first_name' => 'First1', 'last_name' => 'Last1'), array('id' => 2, 'first_name' => 'First2', 'last_name' => 'Last2')));

    $this->assertEquals(array(array('id' => 1, 'first_name' => 'First1', 'last_name' => 'Last1'), array('id' => 2, 'first_name' => 'First2', 'last_name' => 'Last2')), $stubUserModel->getAll());       
}
```

I know that it needs more tests to be considered well unit tested and that the test that I wrote above is useless.

I find it difficult to test because it depends on the class PDOConnection and also the class returned by the prepared statement (the obj instantiated is $objResult in this example). Does this mean that I have to refactor the code and move the PDOConnection dependency outside of this function and maybe pass $objRes as and argument to getAll function to be able to mock it? or there is another way that is less expensive to make it testable?

All suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Due to dependency injection you should pass pdo connection as constructor parametro. Teen pass a mocked connection to tour model faking database operazioni. Testing this object is quite depending on database. So the post of test effectiveness will be testing that pho metods are called with expected parameters. Then this is a Facade, not a model. Call it UserProviderFacade

Comment: You should not mock your database abstraction layer. Instead of writing a unit test you should rather write an integrated test that would hit the database. http://www.mockobjects.com/2007/04/test-smell-everything-is-mocked.html

Comment: @Pherserk, it's been a couple of days now and I find that your answer makes sense, could you add it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to dependency injection you should pass the pdo connection as a constructor parameter. Then you can consider to mock the connection and ensure that expected methods are called the expected times with expected parameters. You can use libraries such as Mockery, Prophecy or phpunit mock objects. Then this is not a model but a provider or repository. So you should call it UserProvider or UserRepository